# What are the differences between Sort Comparator and Group Comparator in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

What are the differences between **Sort Comparator** and **Group Comparator** in Hadoop?

Answer (score 24):

To understand **GroupComparator**, see my answer to this question -

[What is the use of grouping comparator in hadoop map reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728480/what-is-the-use-of-grouping-comparator-in-hadoop-map-reduce)

**SortComparator**:Used to define how map output keys are sorted

Excerpts from the book Hadoop - Definitive Guide:

Sort order for keys is found as follows:

1. If the property `mapred.output.key.comparator.class` is set, either explicitly or by
   calling `setSortComparatorClass()` on Job, then an instance of that class is used. (In
   the old API the equivalent method is `setOutputKeyComparatorClass()` on `JobConf`.)
2. Otherwise, keys must be a subclass of `WritableComparable`, and the registered
   comparator for the key class is used.
3. If there is no registered comparator, then a `RawComparator` is used that deserializes
   the byte streams being compared into objects and delegates to the `WritableComparable`’s `compareTo()` method.

**SortComparator Vs GroupComparator in a one liner:**
`SortComparator` decides how map output keys are sorted while `GroupComparator` decides which map output keys within the Reducer go to the same reduce method call.

Answer (score 8):

**Group Comparator** decides which map output keys **will be united(grouped) into one key,** and of course all collections of values will be grouped too. Usually it takes a first key as the only one for summary collection.

**SortComparator** decides how keys will be sorted in **input of reduce**. By default it uses natural ordering.