# how to implement a group comparator for hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata

Given a class called KeyLabelDistance which I am passing as the key and value in Hadoop,I want to perform secondary sort on it, i.e I first want to sort the keys based on the increasing value of key and then in the DECREASING order of the distances.

In order to to do this I need to write my own GroupingComparator.My question is since the  setGroupingComparator() method takes as a parameter only a class which extends RawComparator, how do I perform this comparison in the grouping comparator in terms of bytes? Do I need to explicitly serialize and deserialize the objects?
And also does having the class KeyLabelDistance implement WritableComparable as follows make the need for a SortComparator as redundant?

I got the use of SortComparator and GroupComparator from this answer : [What are the differences between Sort Comparator and Group Comparator in Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184745/what-is-difference-between-sort-comparator-and-group-comparator-in-hadoop)

Following is the implementation of KeyLabelDistance:

```
public class KeyLabelDistance implements WritableComparable<KeyLabelDistance>
    {
        private int key;
        private int label;
        private double distance;
        KeyLabelDistance()
        {
            key = 0;
            label = 0;
            distance = 0;
        }
        KeyLabelDistance(int key, int label, double distance)
        {
            this.key = key;
            this.label = label;
            this.distance = distance;
        }
        public int getKey() {
            return key;
        }
        public void setKey(int key) {
            this.key = key;
        }
        public int getLabel() {
            return label;
        }
        public void setLabel(int label) {
            this.label = label;
        }
        public double getDistance() {
            return distance;
        }
        public void setDistance(double distance) {
            this.distance = distance;
        }

        public int compareTo(KeyLabelDistance lhs, KeyLabelDistance rhs)
        {
            if(lhs == rhs)
                return 0;
            else
            {
                if(lhs.getKey() < rhs.getKey())
                    return -1;
                else if(lhs.getKey() > rhs.getKey())
                    return 1;
                else
                {
                    //If the keys are equal, look at the distances -> since more is the "distance" more is the "similarity", the comparison is counterintuitive
                    if(lhs.getDistance() < rhs.getDistance() )
                        return 1;
                    else if(lhs.getDistance() > rhs.getDistance())
                        return -1;
                    else return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The code for the group comparator is as follows:

```
public class KeyLabelDistanceGroupingComparator extends WritableComparator{
    public int compare (KeyLabelDistance lhs, KeyLabelDistance rhs)
    {
        if(lhs == rhs)
            return 0;
        else
        {
            if(lhs.getKey() < rhs.getKey())
                return -1;
            else if(lhs.getKey() > rhs.getKey())
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend WritableComparator which in turn implements  RawComparator. Both your sorting & grouping comparator will extend WritableComparator.

If you do not provide these comparators hadoop will internally end up using compareTo of the writable which is your key.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that. Now I have included the code for group comparator also in my question but I get the following error:
KeyLabelDistanceGroupingComparator.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor WritableComparator()
location: class org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator

Comment: When tou extend a class in java and the super class does not have a default constructor this is the error you get. Create constructor in your code and invoke super(). e.g.:  XYZKeyValueComparator() {
  super(MyWritable.class, true);
 }