# How to work with the group comparator in mapreduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, testing, mapreduce

I've read these articles

[What is the use of grouping comparator in hadoop map reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728480/what-is-the-use-of-grouping-comparator-in-hadoop-map-reduce)

[What are the differences between Sort Comparator and Group Comparator in Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184745/what-is-difference-between-sort-comparator-and-group-comparator-in-hadoop)

so I somewhat understand how it works.

The problem is... When testing, without this line

```
driver.setKeyGroupingComparator(groupComparator);
```

I get the folowing output in the reducer.

```
0000000000_44137
902996760100000_44137
9029967602_44137
90299676030000_44137
9029967604_44137
905000_38704
9050000001_38702
9050000001_38704
9050000001_38705
9050000001_38706
9050000001_38714
9050000002_38704
9050000002_38706
9050000011_38704
9050000011_38706
9050000021_38702
9050000031_38704
9050000031_38705
9050000031_38714
```

With it, I get

```
0000000000_44137
902996760100000_44137
9029967602_44137
90299676030000_44137
9029967604_44137
905000_38704
9050000001_38702
9050000002_38704
9050000011_38704
9050000021_38702
9050000031_38704
```

The reducer

```
@Override
public void reduce(CompositeKey key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(key.getFirst() + "_" + key.getSecond());
}
```

I understand it should be something along the lines of

```
0000000000 44137 value1
9050000001 38702 value1 38704 value2 38705 value3 38706 value4 38714 value5
```

but is

```
0000000000 44137 value1
9050000001 38702 value1 value2 value3 value4 value5
```

Where all right halves exept first one are lost. How do I iterate over every right part of the key? Is it possible?

My GroupComparator

```
public class GroupComparator extends WritableComparator {
    public GroupComparator() {
        super(CompositeKey.class, true);
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable a,
                       WritableComparable b) {
        CompositeKey lhs = (CompositeKey)a;
        CompositeKey rhs = (CompositeKey)b;
        return lhs.getFirst().compareTo(rhs.getFirst());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your output looks correct. If you want access to all of the second parts of the key after grouping, you need to put it in the value.