# How to Sort on values in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a history file, that consists of multiple (Topic Pages) each page has 14 lines, from which I need to take an ID and then I count the number of appearances of this particular document, that how many times it appears in this history file. But then I need to display the sorted output with highest number of appearances and then by TOPIC PAGE ID.

In mapper I am just taking the TOPIC key, and using IntWritable writing one against every entry.

and Then in Reducer I just sums it up.

Can't do it using secondary sort, as I get the total count for each TOPIC Page after reduce function has been called.

Output would be like:

TopicID   Appearances
987634    89
678945    87
378956    76

Comment: Apache pig makes this trivial. Have you tried it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort word count by value in hadoop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403857/how-to-sort-word-count-by-value-in-hadoop)

Comment: I want to avoid the use of two jobs.

Comment: Apache pig is other framework, I want it with the Hadoop.

Comment: could you provide a sample input and output for better understanding?