# Sort MapReduce WordCount output by value

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count, secondary-sort

I am currently writing a Hadoop program that outputs the top 100 most tweeted hastags given a data set of tweets. I was able to output all the hashtags with the `WordCount` program. So the output looks like this, ignore the quotation marks:

```
"#USA 2" 

"#Holy 5"

"#SOS 3"

"#Love 66"
```

However, I ran into trouble when I attempt to sort them by their word frequencies (the value) with the code from [here](http://santoshsorab.blogspot.com/2014/12/hadoop-java-map-reduce-sort-by-value.html).

I noticed that the key are integers instead of strings for the program input provided in the link above. I try changing a few parameters in the code to fit my usage but it didn't work out so well, as I don't understand them so well. Please help me!

Comment: You need 2 mapreduce jobs, one which performs the wordcount and the other that sorts the output. One idea of sorting that I can think of is interchanging the key and values, so that it gets automatically sorted. To sort in descending though, you may need to impplement some comparator.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response Amita. I understand the idea completely. The interchanging and comparator are all done in the link I provided. However, I am just having issues with setting the parameters for the mapper and the reducer because the program in the link takes input like "30284 12" instead of "#SOS 12". Basically, I don't know what to change in the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hadoop map reduce secondary sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395998/hadoop-map-reduce-secondary-sorting)

Comment: Use the key as Text type instead of IntWritable. @Ragnall_Mac_Somairle

Comment: added changed code.

Answer (score 1):

You need a second `mapReduce` job, Where the input is the output of your first job.

I have tweaked the code to make it work as per your wish.

For Input

```
#USA 2

#Holy 5

#SOS 3

#Love 66
```

The output should be

```
66 #Love 

5 #Holy 

3 #SOS 

2 #USA
```

I have assumed that tab is delimited between hashtag and count. If it is something else, please change that. The code is not tested, please let me know if it works.

```
package com.my.cert.example;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable.Comparator;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class ValueSortExp {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Path inputPath = new Path("C:\\hadoop\\test\\test.txt");
  Path outputDir = new Path("C:\\hadoop\\test\\test1");

  // Path inputPath = new Path(args[0]);
  // Path outputDir = new Path(args[1]);

  // Create configuration
  Configuration conf = new Configuration(true);

  // Create job
  Job job = new Job(conf, "Test HIVE commond");
  job.setJarByClass(ValueSortExp.class);

  // Setup MapReduce
  job.setMapperClass(ValueSortExp.MapTask.class);
  job.setReducerClass(ValueSortExp.ReduceTask.class);
  job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

  // Specify key / value
  job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
  job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
  job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
  job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
  job.setSortComparatorClass(IntComparator.class);
  // Input
  FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputPath);
  job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

  // Output
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputDir);
  job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

  /*
   * // Delete output if exists FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf); if
   * (hdfs.exists(outputDir)) hdfs.delete(outputDir, true);
   * 
   * // Execute job int code = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
   * System.exit(code);
   */

  // Execute job
  int code = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
  System.exit(code);

 }

 public static class IntComparator extends WritableComparator {

     public IntComparator() {
         super(IntWritable.class);
     }

     @Override
     public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1,
             byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {

         Integer v1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(b1, s1, l1).getInt();
         Integer v2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(b2, s2, l2).getInt();

         return v1.compareTo(v2) * (-1);
     }
 }

 public static class MapTask extends
   Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> {
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
    throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException {
   String line = value.toString();
   String[] tokens = line.split("\t"); // This is the delimiter between Key and Value
   int valuePart = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
   context.write(new IntWritable(valuePart), new Text(tokens[0]));
  }
 }

 public static class ReduceTask extends
   Reducer<IntWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
  public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> list, Context context)
    throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException {

   for (Text value : list) {

    context.write(value,key);

   }

  }
 }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciated it! Unfortunately I'm new to stackoverflow so they won't let me thumbs up for your answer publicly.

Comment: @Ragnall_Mac_Somairle You may accept the answer, if it helped.

Comment: @GyanendraDwivedi Thank you for your help! I am getting an error and not sure why. Could you please assist me with that. Thank you! 
error: incompatible types: Text cannot be converted to IntWritable context.write(new IntWritable(valuePart), new Text(tokens[0]));