# How to sort values (with their corresponding key) in mapReduce Hadoop framework?

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop, parallel-processing, mapreduce

I am trying to sort the input data I have using Hadoop mapReduce. The problem is that I am only able to sort the key-value pairs by key, while I am trying to sort them by value. Each value's key was created with a counter, so the first value (234) has key 1, and the second value (944) has key 2, etc. Any idea on how I can do it and order the input by values?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class Sortt {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text ,IntWritable >{
    int k=0;
    int v=0;
    int va=0;
    public Text ke = new Text();
   private final static IntWritable val = new IntWritable();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws 
    IOException, InterruptedException 
{
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());


        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) 
{
        val.set(Integer.parseInt(itr.nextToken()));
        v=val.get();
        k=k+1;
        ke.set(Integer.toString(k));

        context.write(ke, new IntWritable(v));}
}


    }


  public static class SortReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
        int a=0;
        int v=0;
       private IntWritable va = new IntWritable();
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    List<Integer> sorted = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (IntWritable val : values) {
           a= val.get();
          sorted.add(a);

}
    Collections.sort(sorted);
    for(int i=0;i<sorted.size();i++) {
    v=sorted.get(i);
    va.set(v);

     context.write(key, va);
}
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   long startTime=0;
   long Time=0;
   long duration=0;
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "sort");
    job.setJarByClass(Sortt.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(SortReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(SortReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    Time = System.currentTimeMillis();
  //duration = (endTime-startTime)/1000000;
    System.out.println("time="+Time+"MS");
  }
}
```

Input:

234

944

241

130

369

470

250

100

250

735

856

659

425

756

123

756

459

754

654

951

753

254

698

741

Expected Output:

8   100

15  123

4   130

1   234

3   241

24  241

7   250

9   250

22  254

5   369

13  425

17  459

6   470

19  654

12  659

23  698

10  735

21  753

18  754

14  756

16  756

11  856

2   944

20  951

Current Output:

1   234

10  735

11  856

12  659

13  425

14  757

15  123

16  756

17  459

18  754

19  654

2   944

20  951

21  753

22  254

23  698

24  741

3   241

4   130

5   369

6   470

7   250

8   100

9   250

Comment: This is called "secondary sort", and luckily there's a lot about it online. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395998/hadoop-map-reduce-secondary-sorting is a good start

Answer (score 1):

MapReduce output by default sort by key, and to sort by values you can use Secondary Sort.
Secondary sort is an one of the best technique to sort the reducer output on values, [here](http://www.javamakeuse.com/2016/04/secondary-sort-example-in-hadoop-mapreduce.html) is one complete example.

Comment: What will be the second key؟

Comment: you need to create custom key class based on your sorting value as a key