# How to get a consolidated value in map reduce having multiple reducers

Tags: hadoop

In map-reduce job, if you set 4 reducers to implement the reducer jobs. By doing this, the final output will generate 4 part-files. Like:

```
part-r-00001
part-r-00002
part-r-00003
part-r-00004
```

In this scenario how to get a consolidated value? Say If I am calculating a maximum number? The above case will apparently generate 4 different files, which returns 4 different values.

Comment: What kind of a MapReduce job are you running? Is it Pig, Hive or MapReduce program.

Comment: I am wondering about map reduce program

Answer (score 1):

A short answer would be `use one reducer` in your case.

But when the mapper's make too much output that single reducer can't handle, I suggest you to use `two round` `mapreduce` work.

In the first round, you output consolidated value in each reduce task. In the second round, you use one reducer to figure out consolidated value on the reduced data set of the first round.

If those still won't solve you problem, maybe you should take a look at [grouping comparator in hadoop map reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728480/what-is-the-use-of-grouping-comparator-in-hadoop-map-reduce)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, so we have to run multiple map reduce untill we get the intended output? In that case we have to write another map reduce job for the resultant files. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes.  Also you can define your own `grouping comparator` in MR.