# Mapper's Sorted Output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a list of  data like the following.

```
BLOKA, S1
BLOKB, I2
BLOKB, S3
BLOKA, I2
BLOKA, I1
BLOKB, I1
BLOKB, S3
```

As there are two keys, the data will go to two reducers. How can I achieve that reducer receive value in sorted order like below?

```
BLOK A, [I1, I2, S1]
BLOK B, [I2, I2, S3, S3]
```

Comment: This is what is referred to as a "secondary sort".  There are multiple prior resources that describe how to achieve this.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395998/hadoop-map-reduce-secondary-sorting and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728480/what-is-the-use-of-grouping-comparator-in-hadoop-map-reduce .

Comment: Thanks Chris. That solve my problem!